# Blue screen when using the IAMStreamConfig interface

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

Having a problem regarding the use of IAMStreamConfig interface.

I have the following code to set the output format:

```
private void SetFormat(IAMStreamConfig streamConfig, VideoCapabilities resolution = null)
{
    int capabilitiesCount = 0, capabilitySize = 0;
    AMMediaType newMediaType = null;
    var caps = new VideoStreamConfigCaps();

    streamConfig.GetNumberOfCapabilities(out capabilitiesCount, out capabilitySize);

    for (int i = 0; i < capabilitiesCount; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            var vc = new VideoCapabilities(streamConfig, i);

            if (resolution == vc || resolution == null)
            {
                if (streamConfig.GetStreamCaps(i, out newMediaType, caps) == 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    if (newMediaType != null)
    {
        if (averageTimePerFrame >= 0)
        {
            unsafe
            {
                VideoInfoHeader* vih = (VideoInfoHeader*)newMediaType.FormatPtr;
                vih->AverageTimePerFrame = averageTimePerFrame;
            }
        }

        streamConfig.SetFormat(newMediaType);

        newMediaType.Dispose();
        newMediaType = null;
    }
}
```

Till yesterday I never had any problem with any device, but yesterday I tested this with a new video source, Osprey 850e SDI, and I always get a blue screen when trying to set the format:

```
streamConfig.SetFormat(newMediaType)
```

The format being set is YUY2.

Anyone ever came across a similar issue or has any suggestions?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

These are the details of the media type supplied:

```
Major Type: 73646976-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71  WMMEDIATYPE_Video
Sub Type:   59565955-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71  MEDIASUBTYPE_UYVY
Fixed Size Samples: true
Temporal Compression: false
Sample Size 691200
Format Type: 05589f80-c356-11ce-bf01-00aa0055595a WMFORMAT_VideoInfo
unkPtr: 0
Format Size: 88
FormatPtr: 111386040
```

Comment: It's apparently a driver bug, but if you are looking for a workaround you should include all details you have for the media type supplied as the argument of the call. Most likely something is wrong there.

Comment: @RomanR. I edited the post with details of the media type supplied. Do you think anything else can be useful?

Comment: First of all, it's not YUY2 as you originally wrote. Next, value referenced by `FormatPtr` is equally important.

Comment: @RomanR. Yes, my bad. I was now using AmCap to see the color spaces and frame sizes supported by the video card, and both color spaces are supported. Does this proves that the problem is in my application? Other video cards where working fine.